# Custom template tags in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use **Django Template Tags** to return some **html values** but it happens that the value is returned once and then reused by the browser when refreshed even if I do a hard refresh. It only changes when I reload my development server.
Is there anything that can be done to return the dynamic html files from the template tags each time the browser is refreshed

Comment: You need to mention the exact specific problem with code.

Comment: Denvercoder, please tell me you found a solution :O ? What was it?